# Lines within respective polygon checked with python

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I have two feature classes in a GDB:
- A polygon feature class with 65.000 features and
- A line feature class with 3.000.000 features.
Each of these feature classes has a **polygonid** field that can link the lines with each respective polygon.
I want to check whether the lines with the same **polygonid** are within the respective polygon.
If this is true then on a field called **within** in the line feature class should be filled with **1** and in any other case with **0**.

To achieve this, I wrote the following code:

```
print u'Define line FC....'
LINES = ur'D:\MyGDB\Lines'
print u'    Completed'
print u'Define polygon FC....'
polygons = ur'D:\MyGDB\polygons'
print u'    Completed'
print u'Create the ID list of polygons....'
LINEList = sorted(set([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(LINES,'polygonid')]))
print u'    '+str(len(LINEList))+u' polygons. Completed'
for LINEvalue in LINEList:
    print u'Select polygon with id: "'+str(LINEvalue)+u'"'
    polygon = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polygons,['SHAPE@'],'polygonid = '+str(LINEvalue))
    print u'    Completed'
    cnt = 0
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(LINES,['SHAPE@','within'],'polygonid = '+str(LINEvalue)) as cur:
        for row in cur:
            cnt += 1
            row[1] = 1 if row[0].within(arcpy.Geometry(polygon[0]),'BOUNDARY') else 0
            cur.updateRow(row)
    print u'The '+str(cnt)+' lines of the polygon with id "'+str(LINEvalue)+u'" were checked!'
del POLYList
del polygons
del LINES
print u'!!!FINISH!!!'
```

I expected that it should run normally by filling the **within** field with **1** and **0** but instead it stops on line 19 with the following error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
SystemError: error return without exception set
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Arcpy cursors return a `iterator`, not a `list`. So `polygon[0]` is the reason why you get the `SystemError`.

It seems like you will only have one polygon in your `polygon` cursor. Use the method `.next` to go to the first (and only) polygon.

After:
`polygon = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polygons,['SHAPE@'],'polygonid = '+str(LINEvalue))`
Add:
`polygon.next()`

Then, using `polygon[0]` will return the shape of the first polygon in the cursor.